# How to type a function parameter 'value' in order to always match the type of a dynamic 'key' parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have an object, whose keys' types can be `string | number | boolean`. In order to update this object I have an abstract function that accepts two parameters:

1. `key`: to target a specific key of the object
2. `value`: to update the value of the aforementioned `key`.

The function looks like this:

```js
  // interface 
  interface Frequency {
frequency: "daily" | "monthly";
sendHour: number;
sendMinutes: number;
sendDay: number;
delayStart: boolean;
}

  // react state
  const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState<Frequency>({
    frequency: "daily",
    sendHour: 1,
    sendMinutes: 1,
    sendDay: 1,
    delayStart: false,
  });
  
  
  // updater
  const onChangeFrequency = (
    key: keyof Frequency,
    value: string | number | boolean
  ) => {
    setFrequency((frequency) => ({
      ...frequency,
      [key]: value,
    }));
  };
```

It works, but it also means I coud overwrite a boolean with a number, and typescript would not catch the error. How to make sure the value I enter always match the key's type?

Comment: Could you show us an example of where you call `onChangeFrequency`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with generics **if** you're using a literal for the key when calling `onChangeFrequency`:

```typescript
const onChangeFrequency = <KeyType extends keyof Frequency,>(
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    key: KeyType,
// −−−−−−^^^^^^^
    value: Frequency[KeyType]
// −−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
) => {
    setFrequency((frequency) => ({
        ...frequency,
        [key]: value,
    }));
};

onChangeFrequency("sendHour", 20);      // Works
onChangeFrequency("sendHour", "daily"); // Error as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBlGBDGaC+cAZlBCHAERRrYDGMFA3AFDMD0bcwAdnlEXTRxmPPgNpCAYtQCOSNN1oBPRMzjris+YqUAuSgBNswADZKKcAD6UQEXgAszTNRvTcDACQhIo+7khAAIzQoFg04NwMAWR4kPBQ-AODQl3VIgBFsPTh-IJCwjQM0EyysbFh9QIgIExpuFnxWDjhqOngUHDxmWjsOuABtEjQ5BWUAGgi0GGlh7WUAXTgAXjhUTE60AB4ZkZ0APgAKBFTNWdHsiiNTczGTyK8ffQBGW-DImP9459fXBQNM7IvE5FEpKMoVYjYEzoW74ACUBXYnCQYCMfG6vXgdgAwvZsNwAOZoHZzFQrTYAaTQSgAKkowEI0AAPPDuFBwADW1IgRDgJPOY0OJy52SptPpaB+6gAblD5Pp+Tp+mK6Qz5sw4cs9qo3lNFcoDgchrtlJqltqjidwgA6W3G0lS8IDEXzfSykzyR3whHMfAsZg4vGE4lac4HCj3bxQCgTABMAAYEU64M0AOrQDkoAPcXH4on6pThyM+GOGYxOJPNACiUFIUDg2HZRRQwGoBmYQA)

*(The `,` at the end of the generic is just in case you're doing this in a `.tsx` file; it differentiates between generic parameter syntax and JSX element syntax.)*